# Elasticsearch sorting in parent child relationship

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a parent child relationship in elasticsearch, In a same index. And I want to sort parent by one of their child. Is it possible in elasticsearch.
Please help .

example mapping -

```
PUT /company

    {
      "mappings": {
        "branch": {},
        "employee": {
          "_parent": {
            "type": "branch" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

sample branch data

```
 POST /company/branch/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": "london" }}
{ "name": "London Westminster", "city": "London", "country": "UK" }
{ "index": { "_id": "liverpool" }}
{ "name": "Liverpool Central", "city": "Liverpool", "country": "UK" }
{ "index": { "_id": "paris" }}
{ "name": "Champs Élysées", "city": "Paris", "country": "France" }
```

sample employee data

```
POST /company/employee/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": 2, "parent": "london" }}
{ "name": "Mark Thomas", "dob": "1982-05-16", "hobby": "diving" }
{ "index": { "_id": 3, "parent": "liverpool" }}
{ "name": "Barry Smith", "dob": "1979-04-01", "hobby": "hiking" }
{ "index": { "_id": 4, "parent": "paris" }}
{ "name": "Adrien Grand", "dob": "1987-05-11", "hobby": "horses" }
```

I just want to sort parent by hobby of employees in ascending order.
Please help me.

Comment: would be helpful if you can prove some sample dat and expect result.

Comment: This is possible,  but you need to add more info here , like some example documents and the output you are expecting.